# Schema definition for Spark RDD

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am new to Python Spark. I have below spark data frame & json object

```
df = sqlContext.read.load("result.json", format="json")
```

Json object:

```
df.collect() 

[Row(Dorothy=[u'CA', u'F', u'1910', u'220'], Frances=[u'CA', u'F', u'1910', u'134'], Helen=[u'CA', u'F', u'1910', u'239'], Margaret=[u'CA', u'F', u'1910', u'163'], Mary=[u'CA', u'F', u'1910', u'295'])]
```

when I try to assign field names to above values

```
df.select(Row("Name" =["State","Gender","Year","Count"])).write.save("result.json",format = 'json')
```

I am getting error, below error. Could you please help to how to define schema for the above datafrmae

```
Py4JError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col. Trace:py4j.Py4JException: Method col([class java.util.ArrayList]) does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

After loading a json document you already have the schema, so you can do `df.printSchema()` so you don't need to use the Row class.

So you should be able to do something like

```
df.select(df['State'], df['Gender'], df['Year'], df['Count'])
```

or

```
df.select('State', 'Gender', 'Year', 'Count')
```

When you use the Row class you pass it key-value pairs as named arguments e.g.

`rows = [Row(name='John', age=10)]`

its used to construct a dataFrame with a list of rows e.g.

`df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows)`